# SQLite: Maximum amount across the column and return column name

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I am struggling getting column name for max test score across the columns.

I have managed to get max_score

```
select *, max(Test_1, Test_2, Test_3) as max_score
from result_table;
```

But what I need is a column name. I have many columns to compare so I want to avoid using

```
 case when (Test_1 > Test_2) and (Test_1 > Test_3) then 'Test_1'
```

My desired outcome is in yellow.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s9vi.png]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check all the pairs of the columns.
Use the `CASE` expression like this:

```
select *, 
  case max(Test_1, Test_2, Test_3)
    when Test_1 then 'Test_1'
    when Test_2 then 'Test_2'
    when Test_3 then 'Test_3'
  end as max_score
from result_table;
```

or:

```
select *, 
  'Test_' ||
  case max(Test_1, Test_2, Test_3)
    when Test_1 then 1
    when Test_2 then 2
    when Test_3 then 3
  end as max_score
from result_table;
```